# All right angles are equal to each other

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Why is it that

> All right angles are equal to each other

-a postulate in Euclid's Elements ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_angle)). Shouldn't it be a congruence rather than an equivalence? Isn't this just a special case of the definition of congruent angles?

Comment: I think, he's pointing out that there is only one type of right angle (whereas, for example, there are many types of acute angles).

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/548665/

Comment: @StephenDouglasAllen It seems like that it shouldn't be an axiom but rather a theorem.

Comment: @JacksonH it's only a theorem is it provable strictly from the other axioms. [Proclus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proclus) and [Saccheri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Girolamo_Saccheri) would agree with you though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at an article recently I found the answer. Throughout *The Elements*, Euclid only uses the measures of multiples of right angles. Although he says angles can be bigger or smaller he does not actually measure them.

Source: http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/roots-of-unity/whate28099s-the-deal-with-euclide28099s-fourth-postulate/

Comment: Some of those multiples of right angles are fractions: for example the proof of [Proposition II.9](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookII/propII9.html) involves two angles which are each half of a right angle.  Arguably any angle with a rational number of degrees is a (rational) multiple of a right angle

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct, all right angles are congruent. But let us refer to the definition of angle congruence: equality of angle measure. Therefore, congruent angles have equality of measure. Saying right angles are equal implies congruence, and saying right angles are congruent implies equality.

Answer (score -1):

They are equal angles because they all are 90 degrees. If the right triangle was included in a triangle, then the triangles with right angles would be similar.