# Euclid's fourth postulate and cone points

Tags: geometry

In the following answer [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/548786/688539) ,

> Euclid's right-angle postulate excludes the existence of cone points: right angles at the vertex of a cone are smaller than right angles elsewhere on the cone. So this postulate cannot be proved insofar as the other axioms apply on a cone, which one could argue that they do.

Similar to one of the other commenters on that post, I too am having difficulty in visualizing this statement. I am looking for an answer which can explain the above pictorially , as I couldn't find any pictures on google images illustrating the idea above.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

A cone can be formed by joining the straight edges of some circular sector made out of paper. If a right angle is drawn on the flat sheet at the vertex before joining the edges, then when the cone is formed the angle may not be right anymore *in 3D space*.

Indeed, from the perspective of differential geometry angles cannot be defined intrinsically (from the persepective of an ant that is stuck to the surface) at the cone vertex.

Comment: "A cone can be formed by joining the straight edges of some circular sector made out of paper. " proof?

Comment: @Buraian Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: I would but I Feel I don't have enough background to do it, my geometry is rather weak. If you could link to a proof that also would be appreciated.